# K-fold cross validation in R using the boot package giving inconsistent results

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

I am trying to fit a logistic regression model in R to classify a dependent variable as either 0 or 1. I have a dataset of around 2000 observations and decided to split it in half (training and testing).

After deciding which variables to include in my model, I subsetted the data and fitted the logistic regression as follows:

```
clf <- glm(y~.,data=df,family='binomial')
summary(clf)
```

Then, I tested the classifier on the testing set (1000 observations) and got 0.75 accuracy score.

```
results <- ifelse(predict(model,testdf,type='response') > 0.5,1,0)
error <- mean(r_results != results)
print(1-error) #prints out 0.74984
```

After this step, I decided to crossvalidate using the `boot` package

```
library(boot)

# K-fold CV
error_cv = NULL

# Cost function for binary variable (as suggested by the R documentation)
cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)


for(i in 1:10)
{
    error_cv[i] <- cv.glm(df,clf,cost,K=10)$delta[1]
}

error_cv
```

Now, here is where I encounter a problem. K-fold cross validation as I understand it, does the following (quote from Wikipedia):

> "In k-fold cross-validation, the original sample is randomly
>   partitioned into k equal sized subsamples. Of the k subsamples, a
>   single subsample is retained as the validation data for testing the
>   model, and the remaining k − 1 subsamples are used as training data.
>   The cross-validation process is then repeated k times (the folds),
>   with each of the k subsamples used exactly once as the validation
>   data."

Why is it that `cv.glm()` takes as an argument my already-fitted model? I don't understand what it is doing. Furthermore, if the data argument is equal to the training set, I get error rates of around 0.2, whereas if I set `data = testdf` I get error rates of around 0.4. Since the two sets, `df` and `testdf`, have been split randomly, I cannot explain this large difference and I cannot explain why `cv.glm()` does not (apparently) do the fit and test process it is supposed to do.

What am I missing?

Comment: Interesting question, nicely asked ... I don't get it either ...